# How to create dynamic nested object message in protoBuff?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Am trying to create a message of nested dynamic objects

The resulting ending data structure should look like this

```
"content": {
  "foo1": "bar1",
  "foo2": "bar2"
}
```

Where the keys and, the values inside the content is dynamic and can be defined by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `content` as a `map<string, string>`, so that clients can set any arbitrary key-value pairs (of string type) to it.

```
message Msg {
    map<string, string> content = 1;
}
```

If the value might be any arbitrary types, you can try [google.protobuf.Struct](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto).